# HTTP request with escaped forward slashes in the URL

Tags: php, ajax, rest, http, slim

I am sending an Ajax request to a REST API based on Slim.  How can I include a forward slash in one of the arguments (i.e. named placeholders in the URL)?  For instance, given the following ajax call, I want the values shown as comments in the PHP endpoint.  I recognize I can change to put resource as a parameter, but I would rather not as I use this approach successfully where the arguments are integers and wish to remain consistent.

```
//$('#id').val() = 123
//$(this).prev().text() = https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent
$.ajax({
    type:'DELETE',
    url:'/1.0/editor/'+$('#id').val()+'/'+encodeURIComponent($(this).prev().text())
});
```

Slim endpoint

```
$app->delete('/1.0/editor/{id}/{resource}', function (Request $request, Response $response,$args) {
    //args['id']=123
    //$args['resource']="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent"
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to use backslashes to "escape" the forward slashes in the url? That's utterly pointless. backslashes have no special meaning in URLs and are NOT used for escaping. That's done by encoding metachars to `%xx` values.

Comment: @MarcB  Sorry, forward slashes, not backslashes.  Maybe escaping was a bad word.  I wish a URL like `/1.0/editor/123/"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent"` where the text within the parenthesis comes across as a single argument.

Comment: you'd probably have to double-encode. one encoding to survive the browser, and a second one to keep those internal `/` from being seen as path separators, then.

Comment: @MarcB  Double encode with `encodeURIComponent()`?

Comment: yep. `/` -> `%2F` -> `%252F`

Comment: Well, that got it to the PHP server!  Problem is it now needs to be un-escaped.  I am sure I can search and find a solution, but if you know one off the top of your head, please advise.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: http://php.net/urldecode

Comment: @MarcB  Yep, it definitely came up first on a search.  Thanks again!